# Problem with async requests axios, javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios

I'm trying to get data from an API, but I can't get outside result from the .then.

```
function getChampionMasteryData(championId, summonerName) {  
    var championMasteryData;
    var summonerId = process.env.SUMMONER_ID;

    axios.get(`https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/champion-mastery/v4/champion-masteries/by-summoner/${summonerId}/by-champion/${championId}?api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}`, {responseType: 'json'})
        .then(result => {championMasteryData = result.data})
        .catch(e => console.log(e));

    console.log(championMasteryData);
    return championMasteryData;
}
```

output:

```
undefined
```

Comment: You can't access `championMasteryData` inside of `.then` as it is not in it's closure.  A fix would be to use `async/await`, load the response of the API in a variable and then change the value of `championMasteryData`

Comment: I tried that, and the difference is that I take a Promise pending and i don't find a way to resolve it and take inside data.

Comment: use async await function

Comment: let championmasterydata = await axioscall;
console.log(masteryData)

Comment: [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)